# Two Torahs vs. Tircha Detzibbur

Tags: four-parshiot, hagbah-gelilah, tircha-detzibur

I understand that the main reason for taking out 2 Torah scrolls on a Shabbat when the *Maftir* portion is not the last few verses of the weekly reading, is to avoid *Tircha Detzibbur* ("burdening the congregation" by waiting for the reader to roll the Torah to the next location.)

What if the maftir portion is so close to the weekly reading that it would actually take longer to perform *hagbah* and *gelila* than rolling the Torah and dressing it?

For example, this year, on *Shabbat Sheqalim*, the weekly reading is from *Vayakhel*. The *maftir* of *Shekalim* is in *Ki Tissa*, about 10 or so columns prior.

It seems that calling two people up, having them lift and roll / dress the Torah takes longer then giving the Torah about 2 rolls to the right place.

In such situations, wouldn't it be better to just use 1 Torah to avoid *Tircha Detzibbur*, if that's the concern?